# Как правильно собирать приложение в py2exe?

Tags: python, exe, app, pyqt

Пробую перевести .py в .exe использую py2exe. Для перевода использую такую команду:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py py2exe
```

После сборки приложение отрабатывает, только не имеет доступ в интернет. При запуски файла питона такой проблемы нет. [Папка тестовой программы](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B07aYSnGHQe9dWpsTDhmc1k2SVU/view?usp=sharing).

Подскажите, что я делаю неверно?

Answer (score 1):

py2exe старье. попробуйте Pyinstaller или cx_freeze.